# How to remotely find and copy files without permission errors or having to log in multiple times?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

The issue I have is that our server has a bunch of files in nested directories that I'm trying to find and copy to a folder on my home directory.
This means I can't simply glob all the files like this:

```bsh
scp user@server:"$find_directory/*.genes.results" $copy_directory
```

So I tried to solve this issue with a while loop, and the files successfully copied!!!
**EXCEPT** that it is very impractical because it asks me to log in to the server every time it loops:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#read in starting and ending directory
read -p "Directory that contains all files to move from server: " find_directory
read -p "Directory that will contain all files from server: " copy_directory

path_list=""
ssh user@server find "$find_directory" -name "*.genes.results" | 
while read path_name
do
    echo "$path_name"
    scp user@server:$path_name "$copy_directory"
done
```

So then I thought I would be clever and solve this problem with an elegant little command substitution...

```bsh
scp user@server:"$( ssh gordid@cadillac find "$find_directory" -name "*.genes.results" )" $copy_directory
```

And it found all the files...**EXCEPT** none of them got copied because I got some weird permissions error! Which doesn't make sense because I have all the necessary privileges on both ends of this scp (and also it worked earlier with the while loop).

[image: List of Permission Denie errors]

So now I am running out of ideas. I could go back to the loop and set up an auto login, but I feel like I am overcomplicating at that point.
**What are your thoughts, StackExchange?**

EDIT: Found this [resource](http://go2linux.garron.me/find-copy-files-remote-server-ssh-scp-how-to-script-bash/) which seems to have the same issue. Maybe the automatic login is the only option?

Comment: Use rsync instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming it's ok to preserve the directory structure on the local directory, then you can solve this by using `tar` to create a tarball on the remote side, stream it through the SSH connection and then use `tar` locally to unpack it.

For example:

```
$ ssh user@server "
      cd '$find_directory' &&
      find . -name '*.genes.results' |
      tar -cf - -T -
  ' | tar -C "$copy_directory" -xvf -
```

Also possible is to use `rsync` with an include/exclude list to only copy the files with the extension you're looking for. `rsync` will use SSH by default. It will also preserve the directory structure from the remote server.

```
$ rsync -av --delete \
      --include '*/' \
      --include '*.genes.results' \
      --exclude '*' \
      --prune-empty-dirs \
      user@server:"$find_directory/" \
      "$copy_directory/"
```

The `rsync` options will copy directories and files with the `.genes.results` extension, then exclude everything else. It will prune directories left empty after the copy. Including directories in the first place is necessary, since otherwise `rsync` would not traverse them, which means it wouldn't find the files you're interested on under subdirectories.